# A set where the operator of differentiation is the sum

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let X be the set of differentiable functions in real line. Find an

infinity set  $H$ in X such that

$$ f,g\in H ~~\rightarrow (fg)'=f+g                      $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can find these functions by noting that the condition has to be fulfilled for $f=g=h$, which leads to a simple differential equation:

$$
\begin{align}
(hh)'&=h+h\;,
\\
2hh'&=2h\;.
\end{align}
$$

Unless $h=0$, this implies $h'=1$, with solutions $h=x+c$, and indeed

$$
((x+a)(x+b))'=(x+a)+(x+b)
$$

for all $a,b\in\mathbb R$.

With hindsight, another way to find this solution (but without showing that it's unique) would have been to look at the product rule, $(fg)'=f'g+fg'$, and note that it yields $f+g$ if $f'=g'=1$.

Comment: is there distinct functions f and g such that $(fg)'=f+g$ and f or g is not of the form $x+a$ ? http://math.stackexchange.com/users/6622/joriki

Comment: @joriki  is there distinct functions f and g such that $(fg)^′=f+g$ and $f$ or $g$ is not of the form $x+a$ ?